# wordpress twentyten chid them sidebar problem

Tags: wordpress, sidebar, twenty-ten-theme

I'm using a child theme of Twentyten theme. I want to make a template, where I'll have a left sidebar and it's styles will be completely different from my primary sidebar. I'm using the secondary widget area for this purpose. I've followed this solutin by digital raindrops first,  http://digitalraindrops.net/2010/10/twenty-ten-alternate-sidebar/ ,then used their files. Everything seems ok with the code, but the template isn't in the option where I create the pages. That means I can't select the template I just made from the pages eanu in admin. Any ideas? do I need to put the template file in the parent file directory and not in the child theme directory? Thanks for the help.

note: I can add widget in the second sidebar and the primary sidebar, and they are showing fine in the back. Oh, my primary sidebar has vanished too!! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem myself. I forgot to add register_sidebar in function.php.!